# I cannot print the output correctly using recursion

Tags: java, eclipse, networking, recursion

I am new to networking. I need to design a network with the following topology:

```
The network consists of a number of N hops where each hop is directly connected to the next hop.

The objective is to send a packet from the first hop to the last hop.

I need to imposes the following restrictions on the routing of packets:

    A packet can either pass by a hop, or stop at a hop. At first, no modifications should be done to the packet; the packet is only forwarded to the next hop straight away. In the later case, the packet is modified before being forwarded to the next hop which takes some processing time.

    When a packet stops at a hop, there is a maximum number of hops that the packet is allowed to pass through after leaving the hop before stopping again.
```

I also need to make a method int[] getMinStopsRec(): that implements the naive recursive solution to the problem returning the sequence of hops represented by their indices in the input array in a new array of integers.

MY PROBLEM is THAT I CANT PRINT THE OUTPUT USING RECURSION

and its my code

```
public class Hops {

    private static int[] numberOfHops;
    private static int counter = 0;

    public Hops(int[] hops) {
        numberOfHops = hops;
    }

    private int[] getMinStopsRec() {
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int[] newArray = new int[3];
        counter++;

        if (counter <= 10) {

            switch (numberOfHops[counter]) {

                case 1:
                    list.add(3);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    list.add(1);
                    list.add(4);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    list.add(0);
                    list.add(1);
                    list.add(3);
                    list.add(10);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    list.add(0);
                    list.add(2);
                    list.add(4);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    list.add(0);
                    list.add(3);
                    list.add(5);
                    break;

                case 6:
                    list.add(3);
                    list.add(8);
                    list.add(10);

                    break;
                case 7:
                    list.add(5);
                    list.add(7);
                    list.add(10);

                    break;
                case 8:
                    list.add(3);
                    list.add(8);
                    list.add(10);

                    break;
                case 9:
                    list.add(3);
                    list.add(6);
                    list.add(10);

                    break;

                default:

                    System.out.println("Invalid number : " + counter);
                    break;

            }

            newArray = new int[list.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                newArray[i] = list.get(i);

            }

            return getMinStopsRec();


        }

        return newArray;
    }
}
```